# sort list of custom objects based on enum in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, enums

I have a list of custom object and an Enum class. I have to sort the list based on the enum properties. For example:

My list:

```
val list = listOf(Item(1,Severity.CRITICAL), Item(3, Severity.LOW), Item(2, Severity.SEVERE))
```

My enum class:

```
enum class Severity{
 CRITICAL, SEVERE, MODERATE, LOW
}
```

My sorted list should be:

```
listOf(Item(1,Severity.CRITICAL), Item(2, Severity.SEVERE), Item(3, Severity.LOW))
```

Ordering is done as per the order in enum class. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is your definition of `Item`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `sortedBy` function. It will do the job very easily.

```
val ans = list.sortedBy { it.severity }
```

Comment: What if the position of enum values are changed?

Answer (score 9):

Just attach a value to each enum. This way you don't have to worry about the order in the enum class definition.

```
enum class Severity(val value: Int) { 
 SEVERE(1), 
 CRITICAL(0),
 MODERATE(2), 
 LOW(3)
}
```

And then you could sort the list this:

```
list.sortedBy { it.serverity.value }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple.
Enum:

```
enum class Severity() { 
    CRITICAL,
    SEVERE, 
    MODERATE, 
    LOW
}
```

List:

```
val list = listOf(Item(1,Severity.CRITICAL), Item(3, Severity.LOW), Item(2, Severity.SEVERE))
```

Kotlin ENUM classes has an inside index variable `ordinal`. It is set from 0 in the order of the ENUM you create.

So sort it by just like this:

```
list.sortedBy { it.severity.ordinal }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension function from your enum as below:

```kotlin
private fun Severity.getOrder() = when(this) {
    Severity.CRITICAL -> 1
    Severity.SEVERE -> 2
    ...
}
```

and then, just:

```kotlin
.sortedBy { it.severity.getOrder() }
```

Doing this, you avoid depending on your enum order definition and let your "ordering" class to set that custom order.

Answer (score -2):

Since enum is a comparable,an object of enum can be sorted by extracting the enum value 
from the object, and use compareBy

```
val sortedList = list.sortedWith(compareBy { it.severity })
```

Edit:
If the ordering of the item is a 'natural' part of it, consider implements Comparable interface 
So it will be like

```
data class Item(val index: Int, val severity: Severity) : Comparable<Item> {
    override fun compareTo(other: Item): Int {
        return this.severity.compareTo(other.severity)
    }

}
val sortedList= list.sorted()
```